# Can we always use allowDiskUse:true in MongoDB aggregation query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Aggregation pipeline stages have a limit of 100 MB. To handle large datasets, `allowDiskUse` enables writing to temporary files. 
But have this optional any defect? If haven't, why the default is false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you get an out-of-memory error during aggregation stages like sort, you don't need to use this option.

Note that working with data in memory is very much faster than working with data on hard drive. With hard drive data transfer the aggregation operation has to keep transferring data between the operation, memory and the hard disk.

So, by default `allowDiskUse` option is disabled (or set to`false`). You need to use this option only when needed - e.g., your sort operation needs more than 100 MB RAM and there is an error. Then you will have to use `allowDiskUse:true` to do your aggregation without errors. In such a case, note that when this option is used (set to `true`) the aggreagation operation will be slower.

If your aggregation is working fine and using this option `allowDiskUse:true` has no effect as the operation is able use the memory effectively (and the aggregation ignores this option).

Comment: If all operation less than 100MB, but i set allowDiskUse true, it will be work on hard drive, or only on memory?

Comment: As I said before, memory, only.

Comment: If only memory, i always set true
1. less than 100MB work on memory, and it fast
2. more than 100MB work on hard drive, slow but no error
So i confuse why default is not true, set true have not defect only if you can accept error

Comment: _"So i confuse why default is not true, set true have not defect only if you can accept error "_ First, when this option is set to `false` and the aggregation runs fine - you know there is no problem, If the aggregation stage requires more than 100MB then the process fails with error -- and you know now that there is an issue with your aggregation query or the data --. This will alert you to look at your application, the query and data carefully and allows you to make changes to the query, or do other approaches, etc. If not, you can still use the same query but with lot lesser performance.

Comment: _continued from previous comment_:  If not, you can still use the same query but with lot lesser performance, by using the `allowDiskUse:true`.

Answer (score 1):

The performance impact described in the answer from [@prasad_](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4679320/prasad) still holds true (hard-drive or storage will be slower than memory).

However, starting in MongoDB 6.0 the behavior of `allowDiskUse` has changed as it now **[defaults to true](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.allowDiskUse/)**. That is, unless one explicitly disallows disk use with `allowDiskUse(false)` MongoDB resorts to disk use for (non-index) sorts requiring more than 100 MB memory.